# How do you inject code onto a process without ptrace

Tags: c, linux, code-injection

Is there a way to inject code into an ELF binary without `ptrace`, I can't use it since the program I'm writing this for is using GDB and I don't want to stop the process for the while it's injecting. I read it's possible by using `/proc/pid/mem` but I couldn't quite find anything about how to do it. I don't want to use `LD_PRELOAD` either since it would require restarting the program and I'd want to do it during runtime.

EDIT: I can't use ptrace since the process might already be attached to by gdb

Comment: What do you need this for? You can use `ftrace` to live patch your running programs.

Comment: I'm making a library for C that can patch things, create threads etc

Comment: Do you want to patch your own programs or any?

Comment: any I suppose, why

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/pid/mem` behaves like an image of the process's memory.  To read/write the process's memory, just open `/proc/pid/mem`, then `lseek` to the desired address and `read()` or `write()` however many bytes you want.

For instance, to overwrite the byte at address `0x12345` in the process with `0x90`, you can just do

```
fd = open("/proc/XXX/mem", O_RDWR);
lseek(fd, 0x12345, SEEK_SET);
unsigned char new = 0x90;
write(fd, &new, 1);
```

On a 32-bit system, use `lseek64` instead (and add `#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` before the standard includes).

Note that accessing `/proc/XXX/mem` requires the same permissions as to ptrace the process.  In particular, on some systems you may need to be root.

Comment: I tried that; [code](https://hastebin.com/imivafidiw.cpp) but it failed and errno was set to `Input/output error. I ran it as root, memcpy worked fine though but wouldn't work for remote processes

Comment: @visu: On a 32-bit system, the address might be above 2 GB which looks like a negative offset, which `lseek` doesn't like.  Try adding `#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` at the very top of your program (before the headers) and then change `lseek` to `lseek64`.  With this change, your program works for me.

Comment: @visu: By the way, the `mprotect` stuff is not necessary in your program; `/proc/XXX/maps` isn't subject to memory access protections.

Comment: Oh, when do you need to use mprotect then? Also now I got when writing `Invalid argument` now that I changed the `lseek` to `lseek64` https://hastebin.com/qutulupono.cpp so atleast it kind of fixed the issue

Comment: @visu: `mprotect` is needed if you want to change the page-level protections, so that the process can write its own memory using ordinary CPU instructions.  But `/proc/XXX/maps` bypasses the page-level protections, since the access is done by the kernel.  It enforces its own privilege checks instead (to see if the process is allowed to open `/proc/XXX/maps` at all.

Comment: @visu: Can you please post the updated complete program that fails, the exact error message, and the command you are using to compile it?   The snippet in your last paste looks okay, so the problem may be somewhere else.

Comment: @visu: Also, are you running an actual 32-bit system, or is this a 32-bit program on a 64-bit system?

Comment: It's a 32-bit program on a 64-bit system, since I read that replacing 64-bit asm is a little more difficult in some ways not sure exactly what but the snippet is all that's been changed from the previous, here's the entire thing though, it's odd that it wouldn't let me write; https://hastebin.com/moxelevewe.cpp

Comment: @visu: You forgot to `#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` as I mentioned above.  Without this `lseek64` does not work correctly.

Comment: oh sorry I made the changes from the above hastebins, I had done it in the original file, but as I edited above I opted to use `process_vm_writev` and it works fine; thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

I decided I'd use `process_vm_writev`, which seems to work I don't know why it didn't want to write to `/proc/pid/mem` which is odd.

```
/**
 * @brief write_process_memory Writes to the memory of a given process
 * @param pid                  Program pid
 * @param address              The base memory address
 * @param buffer               Buffer to write
 * @param n                    How many bytes to write
 * @return                     Returns bytes written
 */
ssize_t write_process_memory(pid_t pid, void *address, void *buffer, ssize_t n) {
    struct iovec local, remote;
    /* this might have to be made so that if n > _SC_PAGESIZE
     * local would be split into multiple locals, similar to how
     * read_process_memory works, no fucking clue though if it's necessary */
    remote.iov_base = address;
    remote.iov_len = n;
    local.iov_base = buffer;
    local.iov_len = n;
    ssize_t amount_read = process_vm_writev(pid, &local, 1, &remote, 1, 0);
    return amount_read;
}
```